# CSS override rules and specificity

Tags: html, css

I'm often confused by CSS override rules: in general, I realize that more specific style-sheets override less specific ones, and that specificity is determined by how many selectors are specified.  There's also the `!important` keyword, which plays a role as well.

So, here's a simple example: I have a table with two table cells.  The table itself has a CSS rule which applies to all cells within the table.  However, the second table cell has its own rule which should override the general table rule:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type = "text/css">

table.rule1 tr td {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

td.rule2 {
    background-color: #ffff00;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
    <table class = "rule1">
        <tr>
            <td>abc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "rule2">abc</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

But... when I open this in a browser, I see that `rule2` doesn't override `rule1`.  Okay - so I guess I need to make `rule2` more "specific", but I can't really define any further selectors since I just want to apply it to a particular table cell. I tried adding the `! important` keyword, but that doesn't work either.

I'm able to override `rule2` if I wrap the text node in a `<div>`, like:

```
<td class = "rule2"><div>abc</div></td>
```

...and then make the CSS rule more specific:

```
td.rule2 div {
    background-color: #ffff00; !important
}
```

This works, but it's not exactly what I want.  For one thing, I want to apply the rule to the *table cell*, not the div.  It makes a difference because you can still see the background color of `rule1` as a border around the div.

What do I need to do to tell CSS I want `rule2` to override `rule1` for the `td` element?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

To give the second rule higher specificity you can always use parts of the first rule. In this case I would add `table.rule1 tr`from rule one and add it to rule two.

```
table.rule1 tr td {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

table.rule1 tr td.rule2 {
    background-color: #ffff00;
}
```

After a while I find this gets natural, but I know some people disagree. For those people I would suggest looking into [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/).

Comment: Also, you can omit 'rule1' if you would need to make 'rule2' accessible to all tables. Ex: table tr td.rule2 {background-color: #ffff00;}

Answer (score 17):

The specificity is calculated based on the amount of id, class and tag selectors in your rule. Id has the highest specificity, then class, then tag. Your first rule is now more specific than the second one, since they both have a class selector, but the first one also has two tag selectors.

To make the second one override the first one, you can make more specific by adding information of it's parents:

```
table.rule1 tr td.rule2 {
    background-color: #ffff00;
}
```

[Here](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/) is a nice article for more information on selector precedence.

Comment: isnt it inline style that takes presedence ie <p style="color:red;">Hello</p>

Comment: @NicholasKing: Yes, and I think `!important` has an even higher precedence.

Comment: Since you mentioned specificity, I found this [CSS Specificity Calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/)

Answer (score 5):

The important needs to be inside the ;

```
td.rule2 div {     background-color: #ffff00 !important; }
```

in fact i believe this should override it

```
td.rule2 { background-color: #ffff00 !important; }
```

Comment: While `!important` works I strongly suggest not using it. In my mind it's a bit "hacky", and can often confuse you later in the project. The only time I use it is when I desperately need to override inline css, in which case there is no other option. It's better to get comfortable with selector precedence.

Comment: Thats true i use it to override inline styling on projects such as sharepoint.

Comment: @PerSalbark my answer was more a direct answer to why the code wasnt working rather than the best way to use selectors as i personally think your solution is the best way to achieve the goal

Comment: Hrmpf. Being a C/C++ programmer, I read "!important" as "NOT important", while it means the exact opposite: "very important" ....