# Load child theme CSS after Woocommerce CSS

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to avoid use !important to override the WooCommerce styles. Right now I have enqueued WooCommerce styles and trying to queue them after my child template but nothing seems to work.

```
// Dequeue Woocommerce Style
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_empty_array' );

// Dequeue Parent themes
function understrap_remove_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'understrap-styles' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'understrap-styles' );

    wp_dequeue_script( 'understrap-scripts' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'understrap-scripts' );

    // Removes the parent themes stylesheet and scripts from inc/enqueue.php
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'understrap_remove_scripts', 20 );

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {

    // Get the theme data
    $the_theme = wp_get_theme();
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-understrap-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/child-theme.min.css', array(), $the_theme->get( 'Version' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'popper-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/popper.min.js', array(), false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'child-understrap-scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/child-theme.min.js', array(), $the_theme->get( 'Version' ), true );
    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'woocommerce_theme_styles' );
function woocommerce_theme_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('woocommerce_smallscreen', plugins_url() .'/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce-smallscreen.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('woocommerce_css', plugins_url() .'/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('woocommerce_layout', plugins_url() .'/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce-layout.css');
}
```

Here's a live version of the web: http://ufctrashtalk.com

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: In order to override your css has to be loaded after the rest.

Comment: You seem to dequeue them, queue your child css and then queue them.
I don't know wordpress. But I'd remove the dequeueing and juste queue your child theme without the woocomerce enqueueing.

Comment: I don't want to dequeue all woocommerce styles because I need most of the CSS. I just want to override some parts without using the !important. Thanks!

Comment: Don't dequeue any of it. Just add yours after the woocomerce. That way your ccs should be loaded after the woocomerce and override the rules you specified in your files.

Comment: Even if you leave the style being enqueued before woocommerce you should still be able to ovverride woocommerce styles without using `!important`. Lets say woocommerce styles '.wc_checkout button` and you want to ovverride its styling, you can be more specific in your css targets and it will ovverride the woocommerce styles by targeting `.wc_checkout .any-div-class button`

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned in your question that you're trying to override some WooCommerce css rules, but you just removed all WooCommerce stylesheets from loading with this line of code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_empty_array' );
```

If you want to keep them into page, remove the line of code provided above.

Two ways to achieve your goal - load your stylesheet(s) after WooCommerce default ones. First of all, you don't need this part of code:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'woocommerce_theme_styles' );
function woocommerce_theme_styles() {
  wp_enqueue_style('woocommerce_smallscreen', plugins_url() .'/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce-smallscreen.css');
  wp_enqueue_style('woocommerce_css', plugins_url() .'/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce.css');
  wp_enqueue_style('woocommerce_layout', plugins_url() .'/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce-layout.css');
}
```

Even by default, if you delete the function above, the WooCommerce will load it's files before Theme's one. It's coming from WordPress functions. First loading all plugins, and only after it Themes.

WooCommerce loading them by default, when the plugin is active. `woocommerce.css` stylesheet may not be loaded, and instead of it load `twenty-seventeen.css`, if the Theme of your site is `Twenty Seventeen`.

1. Make the priority of your [`add_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) higher:

   ```
   add_action( 'some-hook', 'some_function', 20 );
   ```

   Here 20 is priority. By default, it's 10. Increasing the priority will fire your function later, which mean that your `.css`, `.js` files will loaded in the DOM later( after all `.css`, `.js` files, which was called with default priority or lower of your ).
   Your function will be:

   ```
   //priority 20 is higer, then WooCommerce ones( 10 )
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles', 20 );
   function theme_enqueue_styles() {

       // Get the theme data
       $the_theme = wp_get_theme();
       wp_enqueue_style( 'child-understrap-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/child-theme.min.css', array(), $the_theme->get( 'Version' ) );
       wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');
       wp_enqueue_script( 'popper-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/popper.min.js', array(), false);
       wp_enqueue_script( 'child-understrap-scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/child-theme.min.js', array(), $the_theme->get( 'Version' ), true );
       if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
           wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
       }
   }
   ```

   This will load your `child-theme.min.css` file after all woocommerce files.
2. Use dependences for your [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) function. For ex., if you want to load your stylesheet only after `woocommerce-smallscreen.css` stylesheet, use it's handler as dependence for your file:

   ```
    wp_enqueue_style( 'some-handler', 'some-url-of-file', array('depends-on', 'another-dependence') );
   ```

   So, you can just use on `woocommerce-smallscreen.css` file using it's handler `woocommerce-smallscreen`:

   ```
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
   function theme_enqueue_styles() {

       // Get the theme data
       $the_theme = wp_get_theme();
       //Here we use dependences
       wp_enqueue_style( 'child-understrap-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/child-theme.min.css', array('woocommerce-smallscreen'), $the_theme->get( 'Version' ) );
       wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');
       wp_enqueue_script( 'popper-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/popper.min.js', array(), false);
       wp_enqueue_script( 'child-understrap-scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/child-theme.min.js', array(), $the_theme->get( 'Version' ), true );
       if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
           wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
       }
   }
   ```

   **Note**: If the file on which your stylesheet dependence not loaded( not exists, plugin not activated ), then your file will not loaded, too, because of broken dependences.

So, after one of steps your stylesheet will load after WooCommerce one's. But even after it you css rules will not override WooCommerce ones because you're using weaker rules, and WooCommerce use strongest ones. Ex.:

WooCommerce: `.woocommerce a.button{}`

Your's:      `.button.add_to_cart_button{}`

Try to use this: `.woocommerce a.button{}` and it will be overriden. You can also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11263488/8053001).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it keeps not working. I have tried both solutions and WooCommerce stills loads after my child CSS.
You can see it here: http://ufctrashtalks.com - if you check the Buy It Now button.

Comment: @user3081614 don't think so. code tested and works. first of all after looking at your website, I noticed that `woocommerce` stylesheets not loading. you are using `add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_empty_array' );`. remove it. and try again

Comment: Just removed the dequeue Woocommerce styles so that you can test it. If you remove the !important from CSS attributes you will see that it will load the WooCommerce CSS. Thanks for your help!

Comment: for ex., can you please, provide some element, which is not overriding from your theme file without `!important`?

Comment: For ex. the Buy It Now button overrides all the WooCommerce CSS with !important, like the background-color, text-color, etc

Comment: it's overrirdes NOT from `child-theme.min.css` file. it's overrides from sass(scss) files. so, the all code you provided not related to the right file. where you put your css rules?

Comment: Yes. I'm using Understrap child theme and coding with SASS. With gulp function it minifies everything into a CSS. So I'm writing everything in the _child_theme.scss. Here's a screenshot: https://d2ffutrenqvap3.cloudfront.net/items/2J2O3h0y1B2o033f1L0T/Screen%20Shot%202018-04-01%20at%2020.31.54.png?v=77a3d465

Comment: ok. so your sass converted to `child-theme.min.css` file, right? but the problem is that in the woocommerce using more detailed rules for target elements, and you don't. ex.`.woo span .a`{something} your : `.a`, and it's don't metter, where you put your code, it will be overriden with detailed rules

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you de-queued WooCommerce styles, but this should solve your problem:

```
// Dequeue Woocommerce Style
// add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_empty_array' );

// Dequeue Parent themes
function understrap_remove_scripts() {

    // wp_enqueue_style('woocommerce_smallscreen', plugins_url() .'/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce-smallscreen.css');
    // wp_enqueue_style('woocommerce_css', plugins_url() .'/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce.css');
    // wp_enqueue_style('woocommerce_layout', plugins_url() .'/woocommerce/assets/css/woocommerce-layout.css');

     // Removes the parent themes stylesheet and scripts from inc/enqueue.php
    wp_dequeue_style( 'understrap-styles' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'understrap-styles' );

    wp_dequeue_script( 'understrap-scripts' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'understrap-scripts' );

    // Get the theme data
    $the_theme = wp_get_theme();
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-understrap-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/child-theme.min.css', array(), $the_theme->get( 'Version' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'popper-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/popper.min.js', array(), false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'child-understrap-scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/child-theme.min.js', array(), $the_theme->get( 'Version' ), true );
    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ufctrashtalk_scripts' );
```

If it doesn't solve the issue, un-comment commented functions, which I doubt is necessary unless you have a reason.

Answer (score 0):

To control the order in which .css files are loaded you just need to specify the $deps argument of wp_enqueue_style()

```
wp_enqueue_style( string $handle, string $src = '', array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, string $media = 'all' )
```

The algorithm that WordPress uses to create the ordered list of .css files to use is very simple and is only 46 lines.

```
  /**
   * Determines dependencies.
   *
   * Recursively builds an array of items to process taking
   * dependencies into account. Does NOT catch infinite loops.
   *
   * @since 2.1.0
   * @since 2.6.0 Moved from `WP_Scripts`.
   * @since 2.8.0 Added the `$group` parameter.
   *
   * @param mixed     $handles   Item handle and argument (string) or item handles and arguments (array of strings).
   * @param bool      $recursion Internal flag that function is calling itself.
   * @param int|false $group     Group level: (int) level, (false) no groups.
   * @return bool True on success, false on failure.
   */
  public function all_deps( $handles, $recursion = false, $group = false ) {
    if ( !$handles = (array) $handles )
      return false;

    foreach ( $handles as $handle ) {
      $handle_parts = explode('?', $handle);
      $handle = $handle_parts[0];
      $queued = in_array($handle, $this->to_do, true);

      if ( in_array($handle, $this->done, true) ) // Already done
        continue;

      $moved     = $this->set_group( $handle, $recursion, $group );
      $new_group = $this->groups[ $handle ];

      if ( $queued && !$moved ) // already queued and in the right group
        continue;

      $keep_going = true;
      if ( !isset($this->registered[$handle]) )
        $keep_going = false; // Item doesn't exist.
      elseif ( $this->registered[$handle]->deps && array_diff($this->registered[$handle]->deps, array_keys($this->registered)) )
        $keep_going = false; // Item requires dependencies that don't exist.
      elseif ( $this->registered[$handle]->deps && !$this->all_deps( $this->registered[$handle]->deps, true, $new_group ) )
        $keep_going = false; // Item requires dependencies that don't exist.

      if ( ! $keep_going ) { // Either item or its dependencies don't exist.
        if ( $recursion )
          return false; // Abort this branch.
        else
          continue; // We're at the top level. Move on to the next one.
      }

      if ( $queued ) // Already grabbed it and its dependencies.
        continue;

      if ( isset($handle_parts[1]) )
        $this->args[$handle] = $handle_parts[1];

      $this->to_do[] = $handle;
    }

    return true;
  }
```

Removing all the error checking this simplifies to

```
  public function all_deps( $handles, $recursion = false, $group = false ) {
    foreach ( $handles as $handle ) {
      $this->registered[$handle]->deps && !$this->all_deps( $this->registered[$handle]->deps, true, $new_group ) )
      $this->to_do[] = $handle;
    }
  }
```

The ordered list is the array $this->to_do[]. To understand this observe that all_deps() is a recursive function and processes dependencies first

```
$this->all_deps( $this->registered[$handle]->deps, true, $new_group )
```

only after dependencies are processed does it add the item to $this->to_do[]

```
$this->to_do[] = $handle;
```

So, the order in which .css files are enqueued is not as important as the dependency relationship and you only need the dependency relationship to achieve the desired relative ordering of .css files.

As a last resort you can modify this $this->to_do[] array before WordPress uses it to send .css files using the filter 'print_styles_array'.

```
add_filter( 'print_styles_array', function( $todo) {
    error_log( print_r( $todo, true ) );
    return $todo;
} );
```

Here I am using it only to dump the $this-to_do[] array but you can modify it before returning.