# How to override the property of outline: none in css

Tags: html, css

How to override the property of outline: none in css. In the parent class there is a property outline: none and in child class i dont need that .

Comment: please provide an exampl from your code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS override rules and specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263488/css-override-rules-and-specificity)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `outline: none !important;` in your child class.

Answer (score 0):

You can give an outline to the child.

`.child { outline: 1px solid  }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the value `unset` or `initial`.

`outline: unset`

> The unset CSS keyword resets a property to its inherited value if the
> property naturally inherits from its parent, and to its initial value
> if not. In other words, it behaves like the inherit keyword in the
> first case, when the property is an inherited property, and like the
> initial keyword in the second case, when the property is a
> non-inherited property.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset