# css several "text-align" declared, which one rules?

Tags: html, css, centering

Minimal reproducible example:

```html
Hello World

<div class="footer">
  <p>This is a test</p>
</div>
```

```css
p {
  text-align: justify;
}

.footer {
    background-color: #433E3F;
    color: #bdcad9;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I have this:
[image]

How do I make the `text-align: center` of the `footer` class overrule the one defined in the `paragraph` elements?

If I take off the `text-align` of the `paragraph` elements, my footer gets centered obviously, but I want to keep the `paragraph` elements justified:
[image]
So that's not a solution :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS override rules and specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263488/css-override-rules-and-specificity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `class="footer"` is on the `div` and not on the `p`, so it will center text within the `div` but not text within the `p`. I would put a class on the specific paragraph that you want to center. For example,

```
Hello World

<div class="footer">
  <p class="center-text">This is a test</p>
</div>
```

```
p {
  text-align: justify;
}

.footer {
    background-color: #433E3F;
    color: #bdcad9;
}

.center-text {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Or, if you just want all paragraphs within your footer div to be centered:

```
<div class="footer">
  <p>This is a test</p>
</div>
```

```
p {
  text-align: justify;
}

.footer p {
    background-color: #433E3F;
    color: #bdcad9;
    text-align: center;
}
```